# How will greedy work in this coin change case

Tags: algorithm, greedy

The problem is **[here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Change-making_problem)**

Say I have just 25-cent, 10-cent and 4-cent coins and my total amount is 41. Using greedy, I'll pick 25-cent and then 10-cent, and then the remaining 6 cents can not be made.

So my question is, does greedy in this case will tell me that there is no solution?

Comment: I don't understand your question.   Clearly the greedy algorithm tells you that there is no solution, because when you apply it you find that ... there is no solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like your problem was answered right in the the Greedy algorithm wiki: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Greedy_algorithm#Cases_of_failure

> Imagine the coin example with only 25-cent, 10-cent, and 4-cent coins. The greedy algorithm would not be able to make change for 41 cents, since after committing to use one 25-cent coin and one 10-cent coin it would be impossible to use 4-cent coins for the balance of 6 cents, whereas a person or a more sophisticated algorithm could make change for 41 cents with one 25-cent coin and four 4-cent coins.

Comment: I actually got it from some other link, but yeah, I wnted to know if Greedy will make any other attempts to find the solution, or does it follow a single path and if it succeeds, then well and good, else it just gives up.
Thanks :)

Comment: @Kraken Greedy, in its simplest form, does not have any form of backtracking. So it's really just "one shot". In this case, it would fail to provide a solution.

Answer (score 1):

The greedy algorithm mentioned in your link assumes the existence of a unit coin. Otherwise there are some integer amounts it can't handle at all.

Regarding optimality - as stated there, it depends on the available coins. For {10,5,1} for example the greedy algorithm is always optimal (i.e. returns the minimum number of coins to use). For {1,3,4} the greedy algorithm is not guaranteed to be optimal (it returns 6=4+1+1 instead of 6=3+3).

Answer (score 1):

It seems that greedy algorithm is not always the best and this case is used as example to illustrate when it doesn't work

[See example](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Greedy_algorithm#Cases_of_failure) in Wikipedia